# Efficiently merging data from all domain controllers

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to merge data from all the domain controllers in a domain.

For example, I sum all **logonCount**s and I select only the latest **lastLogon**. This is done in the `private static User MergeData(User alreadyKnownUser, User newlyRetrieveUser)` method.

Here is my code :

```
foreach (Domain domain in this.Domains)
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> usersFromCurrentDomain = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>();

    foreach (ActiveDirectoryDomainController domainController in domain.DomainControllers)
    {
        DirectoryEntry domainControllerDirectoryEntry = domainController.DirectoryEntry;

        ICollection<User> userFromCurrentDomainController = EnumerateAllUsersInDomainController(domainControllerDirectoryEntry);

        Parallel.ForEach(userFromCurrentDomainController, currentUser =>
        {
            string userId = currentUser.Id;

            if(usersFromCurrentDomain.Contains(userId))
            {
                User retrievedUser = usersFromCurrentDomain[userId];
                retrievedUser = MergeData(retrievedUser, currentUser);
                usersFromCurrentDomain[id] = retrievedUser;
            }
            else
            {
                usersFromCurrentDomain.Add(userId, currentUser);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I think its efficiency is **O(n²)** (right ?).

Is there any way to have a more efficient algorithm ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not **O(n^2)**. It is **O(n^3)**, since you iterate the domains, inside of that you iterate the domain controllers, inside of which you iterate users. If you want to optimize this, then first of all, you should take a look at the call of `EnumerateAllUsersInDomainController(domainControllerDirectoryEntry)`. Wouldn't it be much better, if you had a method of `EnumerateAllUsersInDomainControllers` which would expect a List of `DirectoryEntry`? If you had a method like that, then the optimization would contain the following elements:

- you iterate `this.Domains` and merge `domain.DomainControllers` with a list containing domain controllers
- you iterate the domain controllers in a separate iteration, building a list of DirectoryEntry
- you call the newly created `EnumerateAllUsersInDomainControllers`
- you parse the result according to your needs